# Global Search Result Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to use the global search result page. I couldnt find the coding for it. I want to use that in my visual force page.

Comment: you can't directly use it. You need to manually create it using apex, VF.

Comment: can you give me some tips or code regarding this...

Answer (score 4):

You can use SOSL for this. SObjectsList would be list of objects you want to search. Something like this :

```
String test1 = '*'+test+'*';// test would be getter setter for search box.  
List<List<Sobject>> = [FIND :test1 IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING SOBJECTS_LISt];
```

Comment: but what about the page layout and other things. I want to use the standard salesforce page of global search result, otherwise it will require much more efforts if I design and code all the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As Tushar Sharma said in a comment to your question:

> you can't directly use it. You need to manually create it using apex, VF.

In other words, you can't directly access or change any code related to the default Salesforce search utility. This means anything radical you'd have to create your own custom search using Visualforce and Apex. However, you can have some influence on the search.

When you create (or edit) an object, you'll have an option like below:

[image]

Which allows Salesforce to index records of that object so that they can be searched for on the default Search box.

A simple, hard coded example of a Visualforce Page with a search might look something like this:

**VisualForce**

```
<apex:page controller="myController">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public class myController {
    public List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 10];
}
```

A good article/tutorial to look at would be [Building a Dynamic Search Page in Visualforce by Jeff Douglas.](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/13/building-a-dynamic-search-page-in-visualforce/)